# Check if a date is -5 years from todays date using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I currently have an Excel spreadsheet which I would like to be able to enter a string into a variable to then search the Excel file to return if the variable has depreciated by 5 years using openpyxl, to then print the entire row if the date is less than 5 years.

I currently have the date column from the workbook but I'm unsure as to how I can write the code to check if the date is -5 years from today's date.

Below is my current code...

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime

five_years = 1825
file = 'example.xlsx'
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
date_cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=5, column=6)

m_row = sheet_obj.max_row

print(sheet_obj.max_row)

for i in range(1, m_row + 1):
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=6)
    print(date_cell_obj.value)
```

This prints the entire column of dates which I want to check against.

Any help is much appreciated as always!

Comment: Why not use the datedif() function?

Comment: What is the format of the date column in your excel file?

Comment: the format is - 01/12/2015 (%d-%m-%Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overview: calculate the days difference beween the two dates then divide by 365 days and compare to 5 years

```
import datetime
#https://strftime.org/
d=datetime.datetime.now()

dateList=['2017-12-31','2001-01-01','2010-11-21']

for item in dateList:
     diff_days=(d-datetime.datetime.strptime(item,'%Y-%m-%d')).days
     if (diff_days/365)>5:
         print(item," found")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfect had to just change the date format to - '%d/%m/%Y'